# Allow asp web application in MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-routing

We build a new MVC4 web site. when we tried to replace existing asp.net webforms website with new MVC4 web site there was a web application inside that website which is pointing to different folder which is having asp files. So we want to support that project as is.

example : website1.com is a website name

website1.com/Customasp is web application in different folder which has to be mainitained. 
files in that are hello.asp

website.com/customasp/hello.asp is returning a 404 page. whats wrong with this.

Please help

Comment: What the?...sorry no idea

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create 2 distinct application on IIS.

One for MVC project (root) and second for your classic ASP app which should be defined as virtual directory(customasp) within MVC project.

All that will depend on what version of web server are you using.
You need to make sure that app pool for MVC running on NET 4.0 or better since it is MVC 4 and classic ASP poll running in proper format.

In IIS 7+ it should be set to "No Managed Code". Also make sure that MIME type as well as ISAPI filters properly assigned for both application separately. And if you are using IIS 7+ make sure that ASP mode is enabled because by default it is not.

Comment: Yeah if this is what you are trying to do (couldn't tell from the question) you will need two specific app pools, one managed and one unmanaged, you will also need the HTTP Handler setup in your ASP application for the asp ISAPI DLL.